Is there a way in Apps Script to fill a table from an html file module, not depending on columns header and position?
Submitting a Google module linked to a Google sheet, the module answers are inserted into the right fields of the linked table in the Google Sheet, even if you change the table columns headers and the columns position. Is there a way to obtain the same result, using a custom module in an html file and Apps Script? You could write the initial header names into a hidden row, but it does not seem the best solution.
Thanks

Perhaps an example of input and output would be helpful.

Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Should this question include "python" tag(s)?

Please explain what "module" and "custom module in an HTML file" mean.

When you post on Stackoverflow, you're indirectly asking people for free help (which is fine as it's part of the process). However, given that expectation, you might consider taking more of your own time to ask a clearer question. While it may make sense to you, it is not so obvious to the rest of us. Check this out for asking a clear question,
